# Parallel programming in C not executing instructions

Tags: c, parallel-processing, fork, operator-precedence

I need help with C parallel programming, from this graph:
[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNYCH.png)

I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    int r2;
    printf("---------   Program start   ---------");
    printf("\nBlock A instructions"); //block A
    printf("\nBlock B instructions"); //block B
    r2= fork();
    if (r2==0){ //child
        printf("\nBlock E instructions"); //block E
        printf("\nBlock F instructions"); //block F
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        if (r2>0){ //father
            printf("\nBlock C instructions"); //block C
            printf("\nBlock D instructions"); //block D
            exit(0);
        }
        else printf("\nError");
    }
    printf("\nBlock G instructions"); //block G
    printf("\nBlock H instructions"); //block H
    printf("\n---------   Program finish   ---------");
}
```

And the output is:

```
---------   Program start   ---------
Block A instructions
Block B instructions
Block E instructions
Block F instructionsBlock B instructions
Block C instructions
Block D instructions
```

Why doesn't the program write the other instructions, and why does it write "block B instructions" twice?

---------------------          EDIT:          ---------------------

The new code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main ()
{
    printf("---------   Program start   ---------\n");
    printf("Block A instructions\n"); //block A
    printf("Block B instructions\n"); //block B
    fflush(stdout);
    pid_t r2= fork();
    if (r2==0){ //child
        printf("Block E instructions\n"); //block E
        printf("Block F instructions\n"); //block F
        fflush(stdout);
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        if (r2>0){ //father
            printf("Block C instructions\n"); //block C
            printf("Block D instructions\n"); //block D
            fflush(stdout);
            wait(NULL); //wait for child process to join with this parent, returns no value
        }
        else printf("Error");
    }
    printf("Block G instructions\n"); //block G
    printf("Block H instructions\n"); //block H
    printf("---------   Program finish   ---------");
    return 0;
}
```

The output now is:

```
---------   Program start   ---------
Block A instructions
Block B instructions
Block E instructions
Block F instructions
Block C instructions
Block D instructions
Block G instructions
Block H instructions
---------   Program finish   ---------
```

Sometimes the C and D instructions are written before the E and F instructions, is it normal or should it always be EF --> CD ?
Btw is the code good or are there some mistakes? I compiled it with -Wall and I don't get any error messages

Comment: Compile your code with `gcc -g -Wall`

Comment: Don't ask two questions. Create a new question, and **use the debugger** (`gdb`) before asking the new one

Comment: Use `{printf("Error\n");fflush(NULL);}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<stdio.h>` is [buffered](https://www.unix.com/unix-desktop-questions-and-answers/77640-what-buffered-output.html), see [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) and [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html). You should call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) at appropriate places, in particular before [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).

BTW, the code of your standard libc is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), probably [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). Of course it uses [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). So you should study its source code.

### Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

> ```
> printf("\nBlock C instructions");
> ```

is error-prone. The `\n` could flush the buffer, and should in practice be used as the last character of [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) control format string.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't print the other instructions because of the `exit(0)`, so it will never reach G and H blocks. For the B being printed twice see Basile Starynkevitch's answer.